# Change an image of a called composable in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

A question, maybe a little basic since I am in an early learning phase.
If I want to change the image of a composable when calling it, how would I do it?
I know that this is possible with Int and Strings thanks to the parameters that I define in the original function, but how would it be done in the case of images?

```
@Composable
fun ComposableTest(exampleText:String){
    Column() {
        
        Image  (
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.sample_image),
        contentDescription = null,
            Modifier.size(200.dp))

        //Omit the text code, it's a filler
        Text("exampleText",
            Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
                .width(200.dp)
                .padding(vertical = 30.dp), textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun CalledTest (){
    ComposableTest(text = "Composable Text")
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the source of the image? Is it a url or a resource file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:

```
@Composable
fun ComposableTest(exampleText:String,@DrawableRes img: Int = R.drawable.sample_image){
    Column() {
        
        Image  (
        painter = painterResource(img),
        contentDescription = null,
            Modifier.size(200.dp))

        //Omit the text code, it's a filler
        Text("exampleText",
            Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
                .width(200.dp)
                .padding(vertical = 30.dp), textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun CalledTest (){
    ComposableTest(text = "Composable Text")
    
}
```

Comment: That works exactly as I wanted it to, thank you very much! I just needed to call the new image
fun CalledTest (){
 ComposableTest(exampleText ="Composable Text",img= R.drawable.called_image)